# Call recording Android

Tags: android, recording, phone-call, voice-recording

I am making an application in which I am recording calls, Everything is done successfully except other party's voice. I am recording calls using MIC as an audio source. The most downloaded app on play store also using MIC as a source. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I am not able to record voice of other person

Below is code

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static com.brillinfosystem.voicerecorder.UploadService.recorder;

/**
 * Created by DELLANAND on 21/11/2015.
 */
public class SaveFile {

    //   MediaRecorder recorder = TService.recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String audio_format;


    /* public SaveFile(MediaRecorder recorder)
     {
         this.recorder=recorder;
     }*/
    public File startRecording(String method, String filename, String state, Context context) {
        Log.d("recording Started", "Yo I have been called");
        String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/SalesLineCallRecordings");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String file_name = filename;
        try {
            //   audiofile = File.createTempFile(filename, ".amr", sampleDir);
            audiofile = new File(sampleDir, file_name + "-" + out + state + ".aac");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("save exception", "error" + e);
        }
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

//                                 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
/*
        try {
            MediaRecorder r = new MediaRecorder();
            r.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            r.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            r.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            r.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            r.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
            r.start();
            r.stop();
            r.reset();
            r.release();
            r = null;
            TService.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("State" , "Your phone does not support VOICE_CALL");
            MediaRecorder r = new MediaRecorder();
            r.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
            r.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            r.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            r.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                r.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
            r.start();
            r.stop();
            r.reset();
            r = null;
            TService.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        }

*/

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0);


        //        TService.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
//        TService.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        //TService.recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        //TService.recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Problem", "recoder.prepare has problem");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
        return audiofile;
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver class

```
public class TService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;
    private static String type;
    private Handler handler;
    Timer timer;
    AudioDbHelper audioDbHelper;
    Audio audio;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    static private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";

    public SaveFile SaveRecording= new SaveFile();
    static File audioFile;
    //Handler updateHandler = new Handler();
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String outCall;
        public static boolean wasRinging = false;
        public static boolean setUpRecording = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

            audio = new Audio();
            audioDbHelper = new AudioDbHelper(context);


            SharedPreferences settings =context.getSharedPreferences("AUDIO_SOURCE", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            this.context=context;


                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                    if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                        state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "state changed : " + state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("State ", state);
                        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                            String inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                            editor.putString("inCall", inCall);
                            editor.commit();
                            wasRinging = true;
                            setUpRecording = true;
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "INcoming : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.d("Incoming Call", " from : " + inCall + "wasRinging : " + wasRinging);
                        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                            String inCall = settings.getString("inCall", "");
                            Log.d("message", " Oh ! he picked the call" + inCall);
                            if (wasRinging == true) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.d("Answered the call", "from :" + inCall);
                                if (setUpRecording) {
                                    recordstarted = true;
                                    setUpRecording = false;
                                    //            SaveRecording.startRecording();
                                    try {
                                        String method = settings.getString("AUDIO_SOURCE", "");
                                        Log.d("message", method + " : " + inCall);
                                        audioFile=SaveRecording.startRecording(method, inCall, "-In" , context);
                                        Log.d("recording Stared","File name" + audioFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        Log.d("Recording Exception1 : ", e.toString());
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                            wasRinging = false;
                            Toast.makeText(context, "REJECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (recordstarted) {
//                            recorder.stop();
                                Log.d("Message", "Stopping recording");
                                SaveRecording.stopRecording();
//                            saverecordings.stopRecording();
                                Thread xx= new Thread(){
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            Log.d("Thread" , "initiated" + audioFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                                            sleep(1000);
                                            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                                            //NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr;
                                            if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())//
                                            {
                                                {
                                                    type = "yes";
                                                    Log.e("stopped","");
                                                 //   uploadActivity(true, audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                               // uploadActivity(false, audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                            }

                                            Log.d("Thread" , "Executed");
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e){
                                            Log.d("thread Exception" , e.toString());
                                        }
                                    }
                                };
                                xx.start();

                                //SaveFile.recorder.stop();
        //                        updateHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1000);
                                recordstarted = false;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                    if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                        outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //                   saverecordings.startRecording();
                        try {
                            String method = settings.getString("AUDIO_SOURCE", "");
                            Log.d("message", method);
                            audioFile=SaveRecording.startRecording(method, outCall, "-Out", context);
                            Log.d("recording Stared","File name" + audioFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Recording Exception2", e.toString());
                        }
                        recordstarted = true;
                        setUpRecording = false;

                    }
                }

        }

    private void uploadActivity(boolean isConnected, String fileName) {
        if (isConnected) {
            Log.e("", "File path paras" + fileName);
            //new UploadAsync().execute(mFilePath);
            type = "yes";
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, UploadService.class);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            intent.putExtra("audioFile", fileName);
            context.startService(intent);
        } else {

            audio.setAudioRecording(mFilePath);

            audioDbHelper.addAudio(audio);


        }

    }
}
```